# Can I load solr schema file from another server?

Tags: solr

I am running solr on 5 different instance. Making change in schema/dataconfig file is a big task as I need to make changes on each server.
Can I load schema file from a server? So that same path can be defined in each solrconfig and changes will be reflected on each solr instance.

Comment: Just put your config on a shared filesystem that all your instances can access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Solr on multiple instances, you should *really* consider moving to a cluster based installation (i.e. SolrCloud). This will give you a common schema across servers and allow you to easily create collections and make changes across all nodes in your network at the same time.

You can use a shared file system, but it'll still require you to access each server (which you can do through the core API if you want to automate it) to reload the core to make it pick up any changes to the schema.